# Sum of squared differences question

Tags: statistics, summation, proof-explanation, statistical-inference

I'm completing a homework question and I need to prove the following:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} ||\vec{y} - \vec{x}_{i}||^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} ||\vec{x}_{i} - \vec{\bar{x}}||^{2} + N||\vec{y}-\vec{\bar{x}}||^{2}
$$

where $\vec{\bar{x}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \vec{x}_{i}$ and $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm and these are all vectors.

I think I probably need to do something similar to the proof for the sample variance but not sure how to modify it when I have a $y$ in now.

Comment: Is this an Euclidean norm or  a general norm?

Comment: This is the Euclidean norm - I should've said, edited the question now

Comment: If you prove this for $y=0$ you can prove it for any $y$ by changing $x_i$ to $x_i-y$.  For $y=0$ use brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} ||\vec{y} - \vec{x}_{i}||^{2} & = \sum_{i=1}^{N} ||(\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}}_{i}) + (\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i})||^{2} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{N} ((\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}}) + (\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i})) ((\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}}) + (\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i}))^{T} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}})(\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}})^{T} + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}})(\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i})^{T} + \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i})(\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i})^{T} \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{N} || \vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i} ||^{2} + N ||\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}}||^{2}
\end{align*}

since

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\vec{y} - \vec{\bar{x}})(\vec{\bar{x}} - \vec{x}_{i})^{T} & = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j} (y_{j} - \bar{x}_{j})(\bar{x}_{j} - x_{ij}) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j} (y_{j}\bar{x}_{j} - y_{j}x_{ij} - \bar{x}_{j}^{2} + \bar{x}_{j}x_{ij}) \\
& = \sum_{j} \Bigg[ Ny_{j}\bar{x}_{j} - y_{j} \sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ij} - N\bar{x}_{j}^{2} + \bar{x}_{j}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{ij} \Bigg] \\
& = \sum_{j} \Bigg[ Ny_{j}\bar{x}_{j} - y_{j}N\bar{x}_{j} - N \bar{x}_{j}^{2} + \bar{x}_{j}N\bar{x}_{j} \Bigg] \\
& = \sum_{j} 0 \\
& = 0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$(y-x_i)(y-x_i)=((y-\overline x)+(\overline x-x_i))((y-\overline x)+(\overline x-x_i))
\\=(y-\overline x)(y-\overline x)+2(y-\overline x)(\overline x-x_i)+(\overline x-x_i)(\overline x-x_i).$$

Now take the average over $i$.

Comment: But I have norms here, if I take the sum over $i$ and we have norms instead of brackets, how does the cross products cancel out?

Comment: @RyanChan: there are no cross products here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant cross product not as in the dot product, but the terms $2||y-\bar{x}|| ||\bar{x}-x_{i}||$

Comment: @RyanChan: there are no such terms in the development. When averaging, the middle dot product cancels out.

Comment: Sorry I'm just confused - the term is in the hint that you gave?

Comment: @RyanChan: I don't see a single norm bar in my answer. Review the definition of the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91512/discussion-between-ryan-chan-and-yves-daoust).